# Get raw transaction from hash

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, raw-transaction

I wonder if there is an equivalent to bitcoind's getrawtransaction, i.e., a command to dump a raw transaction in hex format, given its hash id.

I am working preferably in geth.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is `eth.getRawTransaction(<txhash>)` now.

*Edit*:
Please check that you're using an up-to-date version of geth. It's part of the current release (v.1.8.6) and was introduced some time ago. You can also see it in the source code:
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/ca64a122d33008c155c35a9d0e78cfbcafb1820a/internal/web3ext/web3ext.go (look for `getRawTransaction`)
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/ec8ee611caefb5c5ad5d796178e94c1919260df4/internal/ethapi/api.go (look for `GetRawTransactionByHash`)

input: transaction hash
output: bytes of the corresponding transaction

Comment: Can you please improve & expand this answer by providing links to documentation and the call/response?

Comment: Is this real? It seems that this call does not exist

Comment: **There isn't `eth.getRawTransaction()`. What are you talking about?**

Comment: I am probing a Geth client version 1.8.15 and this method does not seem to exist. This call returns 405 Method Not Allowed:                     
                    
                                        
curl -i -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getRawTransaction","params":["0x14f00d6f024a1d19d1d93948627020c5b75fc6b2a9fabb256dd2320953834d96"],"id":1}' <client_url>

The same happens if the method is eth_getRawTransactionByHash.

Answer (score 6):

There is an "undocumented" method `eth_getRawTransactionByHash` from JSON-RPC

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data \
'{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getRawTransactionByHash","params":["<TX_HASH>"],"id":1}' http://localhost:8545
```

<TX_HASH> - transaction id

Comment: If I call this, I get 405 Method Not Allowed. This method does not seem to exist on version 1.8.15.

Comment: But it does work in Geth v1.9.11

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [getTransactionByHash()](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/blob/78990aca283f67ceb26ed70c8eb82008424aaf64/JSON-RPC.md#eth_gettransactionbyhash) of the JSON-RPC API.

```
eth_getTransactionByHash

Returns the information about a transaction requested by transaction hash.

Parameters

DATA, 32 Bytes - hash of a transaction
params: [
   "0xb903239f8543d04b5dc1ba6579132b143087c68db1b2168786408fcbce568238"
]
Returns

Object - A transaction object, or null when no transaction was found:

hash: DATA, 32 Bytes - hash of the transaction.
nonce: QUANTITY - the number of transactions made by the sender prior to this one.
blockHash: DATA, 32 Bytes - hash of the block where this transaction was in. null when its pending.
blockNumber: QUANTITY - block number where this transaction was in. null when its pending.
transactionIndex: QUANTITY - integer of the transactions index position in the block. null when its pending.
from: DATA, 20 Bytes - address of the sender.
to: DATA, 20 Bytes - address of the receiver. null when its a contract creation transaction.
value: QUANTITY - value transferred in Wei.
gasPrice: QUANTITY - gas price provided by the sender in Wei.
gas: QUANTITY - gas provided by the sender.
input: DATA - the data send along with the transact
```

Comment: That returns a json description, not the raw transaction

Comment: It is possible to construct the raw transaction from the data returned from the getTransactionByHash() RPC call.

Answer (score 2):

You can also find the raw transaction hex on etherscan.io by going to a transaction, picking `Tools & Utilities` and choosing `Get Raw TxHash`. See for example:

https://etherscan.io/getRawTx?tx=0x248b16e4cb8a624ab4bb3125a3a2cf6bd6d21200b773e3d9c1f0738b1b09dd22

If you want to do this programatically with `geth`, I present a solution for that here:
[Can I get the raw transaction using Nethereum?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/60480/can-i-get-the-raw-transaction-using-nethereum)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way in Python:

```
import web3
from eth_account._utils.legacy_transactions import (
    encode_transaction,
    serializable_unsigned_transaction_from_dict,
)

w3 = web3.Web3(web3.HTTPProvider("https://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"))
hash = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
tx = w3.eth.getTransaction(hash)

def recover_raw_transaction(tx):
    """Recover raw transaction for replay.

    Inspired by: https://github.com/ethereum/eth-account/blob/1d26f44f6075d6f283aeaeff879f4508c9a228dc/eth_account/_utils/signing.py#L28-L42
    """
    transaction = {
        "chainId": tx["chainId"],
        "nonce": int(tx["nonce"], 16),
        "maxPriorityFeePerGas": int(tx["maxPriorityFeePerGas"], 16),
        "maxFeePerGas": int(tx["maxFeePerGas"], 16),
        "gas": int(tx["gas"], 16),
        "to": Web3.toChecksumAddress(tx["to"].lower()),
        "value": int(tx["value"], 16),
        "accessList": tx["accessList"],
    }
    if "data" in tx:
        transaction["data"] = tx["data"]
    if "input" in tx:
        transaction["data"] = tx["input"]
    
    v = int(tx["v"], 16)
    r = int(tx["r"], 16)
    s = int(tx["s"], 16)
    unsigned_transaction = serializable_unsigned_transaction_from_dict(transaction)
    return "0x" + encode_transaction(unsigned_transaction, vrs=(v, r, s)).hex()

raw_tx = recover_raw_transaction(tx)
```

If some basic fields like `access_list` are missing when you retried the tx by hash, add them manually.

Answer (score 0):

The node I'm consuming doesn't support `eth_getTransactionByHash`
So similarly to Nikolay answer, this is how I did it using ethers.js v5 (and TypeScript) instead of web3.py

```typescript
import { Transaction } from "@ethersproject/transactions";

/**
 * Serializes a transaction object into a raw transaction string.
 * This function takes a Transaction object, ensures it is fully signed,
 * constructs the unsigned transaction object, and then serializes it with the signature.
 * It also verifies the serialization process by comparing the computed transaction hash
 * with the original transaction hash.
 *
 * @param {Transaction} transaction - The transaction object from Ethers.js.
 * @returns {string} The serialized raw transaction.
 */
const transactionToRawTransaction = (
  transaction: TransactionResponse,
): string => {
  const type0Fields = { gasPrice: transaction.gasPrice };
  const type1Fields = { ...type0Fields, accessList: transaction.accessList };
  const type2Fields = {
    accessList: transaction.accessList,
    maxFeePerGas: transaction.maxFeePerGas,
    maxPriorityFeePerGas: transaction.maxPriorityFeePerGas,
  };
  const typeFileds = [type0Fields, type1Fields, type2Fields];
  const extraFields = typeFileds[transaction.type ?? 0];
  const unsignedTx = {
    chainId: transaction.chainId,
    data: transaction.data,
    gasLimit: transaction.gasLimit,
    nonce: transaction.nonce,
    to: transaction.to,
    type: transaction.type,
    value: transaction.value,
    ...extraFields,
  };
  assert.ok(transaction.r);
  const signature = {
    r: transaction.r,
    s: transaction.s,
    v: transaction.v,
  };
  const serialized = ethers.utils.serializeTransaction(unsignedTx, signature);
  // double check things went well
  assert.strictEqual(ethers.utils.keccak256(serialized), transaction.hash);
  return serialized;
};

/**
 * Fetches a transaction from the blockchain using its hash and serializes it into a raw transaction string.
 * This function retrieves the transaction details using the provided hash, ensuring the transaction exists,
 * and then utilizes `transactionToRawTransaction` to serialize the transaction.
 * This is useful if we want to replay a raw transaction in local or in the tests.
 *
 * @param {Provider} provider - The Ethers.js provider instance to interact with the blockchain.
 * @param {string} hash - The hash of the transaction to fetch and serialize.
 * @returns {Promise<string>} A promise that resolves to the serialized raw transaction string.
 */
const transactionHashToRawTransaction = async (
  provider: Provider,
  hash: string,
): Promise<string> => {
  const transaction = await provider.getTransaction(hash);
  const serialized = transactionToRawTransaction(transaction);
  return serialized;
};
```

It's much easier with Ethers v6 is much easier since the `ethers.Transaction` object has a `serialized` attribute.

```typescript
import { TransactionResponseParams } from "ethers";

const transactionToRawTransaction = (
  transaction: TransactionResponseParams,
): string => {
  const serialized = Transaction.from(transaction).serialized;
  // double check things went well
  assert.strictEqual(keccak256(serialized), transaction.hash);
  return serialized;
};
```