# Replaying Ethereum transactions, how could I extract the "from" account key from an existing transaction

Tags: web3js, json-rpc, web3.py, ethers.js

I'm trying to replay transactions that exist in one chain on another.

I can replicate all transaction arguments that are available through `eth_getTransactionByHash`, but now need to sign the transaction. How do I extract the signing information from the committed transaction so that I'm able to resubmit with `eth_sendRawTransaction`.

Also welcome responses in `web3.py`, `web3.js`, `ethers.js` or any other preferred json-rpc SDK.

Existing code using `web3.py` that doesn't work:

```py
tx = fallback_web3.eth.getTransaction(individual_tx_hash)
transaction = {
  "from": tx["from"],
  "to": tx["to"],
  "gas": tx["gas"],
  "gasPrice": tx["gasPrice"],
  "value": tx["value"],
  "nonce": tx["nonce"],
}
if "data" in tx:
  transaction["data"] = tx["data"]
w3.eth.sendTransaction(transaction)
```

Comment: Function `eth_sendRawTransaction` doesn't require you to pass the `from` value, as it is already embedded in the raw transaction itself (which you need to pass to this function).

Comment: @goodvibration exactly - and the question is how am I able to build up this raw transaction signature. I'm just using the RPC-API because it's most familiar across both JS/Python users.

Comment: Just take the raw transaction as is.

Comment: Is there an API call for getting the raw transaction? If I use `getTransactionByHash` it's giving me: hash, nonce, v, r, s, etc. individually.

Comment: BTW, why don't you simply use web3.js function [getTransaction](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth.html#gettransaction)?

Comment: I'm using `web3.py` so using something very similar.

Comment: If it's very similar then you shouldn't have any problem getting the `from` field value.

Comment: Note that the signature of the transaction differs from one chain to another since the EIP-155 (https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-155) to protect against replay attacks.

Comment: I can get the `from` field value as long as all the other values but now I need to sign the transaction.

Thanks @clement - yes I'm keeping the chain_id the same.

Comment: You can use web3.eth.signTransaction : https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth.html#signtransaction. It will return the raw tx.

Comment: @clement There is `signTransaction` in web3.py also but it requires the private key. I don't think signing will work because there is no way to get the private keys for these users.

Comment: To send a transaction you must sign it before. So if you don't have the private key there is no way to broadcast the tx.

Comment: @clement are you suggesting that replay attacks were only possible because the attackers knew the private keys? I effectively want to do a replay attack on a local fork of mainnet. It should be possible by using the raw transaction, which was already signed on mainnet.

Comment: You're right, if your two chains have the same chainId, then just sending the raw transaction should work.

Comment: @clement Do you know how to reconstruct the raw transaction using JSON RPC data?

Answer (score 2):

There is an undocumented `eth_getRawTransactionByHash` method now in `geth` nodes.

[Get raw transaction from hash](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/get-raw-transaction-from-hash)

After getting the raw transaction, it can be directly replayed using `eth_sendRawTransaction` as long as all the parameters are the same according to EIP-155 (https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-155) `(nonce, gasprice, startgas, to, value, data, chainid, 0, 0)`.